# how to add another table in existing realm android

Tags: android, realm

I have already a database with few tables. I need to add another table to existing database, but I don't find any ways in migration class.

```
  Table personTable = realm.getTable(Person.class);
        Table petTable = realm.getTable(Pet.class);
        petTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "name");
        petTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "type");
        long petsIndex = personTable.addColumnLink(ColumnType.LINK_LIST, "pets", petTable);
        long fullNameIndex = getIndexForProperty(personTable, "fullName");


        for (int i = 0; i < personTable.size(); i++) {
            if (personTable.getString(fullNameIndex, i).equals("JP McDonald")) {
                personTable.getUncheckedRow(i).getLinkList(petsIndex).add(petTable.add("Jimbo", "dog"));
            } 
        } 
        version++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave above already has that

```
Table petTable = realm.getTable(Pet.class);
petTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "name");
petTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "type");
long petsIndex = personTable.addColumnLink(ColumnType.LINK_LIST, "pets", petTable);
```

Note that in the example, version 1 doesn't have Pet table until version 2.